# Periodic table with css

Tags: css, styling

Good day!

So currently I have a problem in creating a periodic table using only external css file (I'm not allowed to use  tag).

Here is the sample:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <title>Periodic Table</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="s3372661.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="row_0">
            <div id="1" class="element pos_0"> <span class="number">1</span>
                <br> <span class="symbol">H</span>
                <br> <span class="name">Hydrogen</span>
                <br> <span class="molar">1.00794</span>
                <br> <span class="group"></span>
                <br>
            </div>
            <div class="element pos_1"></div>
            <div class="element pos_2"></div>
            <div class="element pos_3"></div>
            <div class="element pos_4"></div>
            <div class="element pos_5"></div>
            <div class="element pos_6"></div>
            <div class="element pos_7"></div>
            <div class="element pos_8"></div>
            <div class="element pos_9"></div>
            <div class="element pos_10"></div>
            <div class="element pos_11"></div>
            <div class="element pos_12"></div>
            <div class="element pos_13"></div>
            <div class="element pos_14"></div>
            <div class="element pos_15"></div>
            <div class="element pos_16"></div>
            <div id="2" class="element pos_17"> <span class="number">2</span>
                <br> <span class="symbol">He</span>
                <br> <span class="name">Helium</span>
                <br> <span class="molar">4.002602</span>
                <br> <span class="group">Element Noble p</span>
                <br>
            </div>
    </body>
    </htmt>
```

and the css file:

```
body {
    background-color: #FFF;
    width:960px;
    display:table;
}
div {
    display: table-row;
    vertical-align: inherit;
    border-radius: 7px;
    -moz-border-radius: 7px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 9px;
    border: 3px solid #FFF;
    background-color: red;
}
.element {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: inherit;
    min-width: 5em;
    border: 2px #FFF solid;
    background-color: inherit;
}
.number {
    font-size:9px;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: white;
}
.symbol {
    font-size:20px;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: white;
    font-weight:bold;
}
.name {
    font-size:15px;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: white;
    font-style:italic;
}
.molar {
    font-size:10px;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: white;
}
.group {
    font-size:15px;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: white;
}
```

The problem is how can I make those unwanted block to disappear without using specificity for each block?

Such as:

```
#row_0 .element.pos_1 {
    background-color: white
}
```

Comment: Link to [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/sCf2P/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are CSS3 selectors allowed?

```
.element:empty {
   visibility: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can achieve it using CSS3 like below... It will hide the `DIV`... Please change the property if required

```
div[class^=pos_]{
 display:none !important;
}
```

Updated CSS for element class is below: remove `display: table-cell;`

```
 div {display: table-row; vertical-align: inherit; border-radius: 7px; -moz-border-radius: 7px; -webkit-border-radius: 9px; border: 3px solid #FFF; }
 .element{text-align: center; padding: 10px 5px;  vertical-align: inherit; min-width: 5em; border: 2px #FFF solid; background-color: red; }
```

Comment: If you set it to display: none, they all will collapse and the result would be that Hydrogen and Helium would be next to each other, which is wrong. I think visibility: hidden would be better

Comment: @JonasGrumann  Yes. As per my knowledge `Visibility:hidden` will  hide the `div` but place will be occupied... so I had a thought of using display:none property so that these `DIV` will come closer... same thing is happening `visibility:hidden` property also because there is `div` class with property `background-color:red` and same is used in class `element`. I have updated the answer by updating `DIV` and `element` classes

Answer (score 0):

You could use visibility: hidden. That would hide the elements without removing them from the box model (thus, they still occupy space). But you'll still be left with empty html elements. I think using positioning or transforms or a combination of floats would be better:

```
div[class^=pos_]{
 visibility: hidden;
}

/* and then reset visibility for the elements that need to be visible */
.pos_1 {
 visibility: visible;
}
```

I made a fiddle of this working solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/jonigiuro/sCf2P/1/

Comment: I applied your code but in other rows from pos_1 to pos_16 were disappeared as well, the html sample I just put up is just only a first row of periodic table. But anyway, the solution from Ilya Streltsyn works well for me so thanks for your effort and have a nice day!